# Bibliography not showing

Tags: bibliographies

citations.bib contains:

```
@Book{hicks2001,
 author    = "von Hicks, III, Michael",
 title     = "Design of a Carbon Fiber Composite Grid Structure for the GLAST
              Spacecraft Using a Novel Manufacturing Technique",
 publisher = "Stanford Press",
 year      =  2001,
 address   = "Palo Alto",
 edition   = "1st",
 isbn      = "0-69-697269-4"
}
```

The tex file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}
\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography 

\end{document}
```

This command will **not** print the bibliography, although there is no compiling error. What's the problem? I'm using TeXstudio in Windows 8.1. I have tried using XeLatex + Biber, PdfLatex + Biber, PdfLatex + BibTeX.

Update: Now, I included

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

and I got error:

```
No file untitled.bbl
```

Comment: Isn't your problem causing the year? `2001` -> `"2001"`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I have no problem compiling it. Are the .bib file and the .tex file in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same directory.

Comment: can you run biber from the command line?

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I can only use TexStudio.

Comment: I'm using Windows 8.1. What's the purpose of running `biber myfile`?

Comment: @user74158 - One needs to run an external program -- either `biber` or `bibtex` -- to create the bibliography.

Answer (score 2):

Judging from some of the information provided among the comments, it may be the case that you (i) can't invoke `biber` from within TeXstudio and (ii) don't know how to open a command window to run `biber` "by hand". I take it you do know how to execute `bibtex` from within TeXstudio.

If that's the case, and if your bibliographic entries don't contain any special, i.e., non-7bit-ASCII characters that will create problems under BibTeX, you could proceed by specifying the option `backend=bibtex` when loading the `biblatex` package. Then, as usual, run latex, bibtex, and latex twice more to get all references and all citation callouts fully updated.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}  % create "citations.bib" on-the-fly
\begin{filecontents*}{citations.bib}
@Book{hicks2001,
   author    = "von Hicks, III, Michael",
   title     = "Design of a Carbon Fiber Composite Grid Structure for the 
                GLAST Spacecraft Using a Novel Manufacturing Technique",
   publisher = "Stanford Press",
   year      =  2001,
   address   = "Palo Alto",
   edition   = "1st",
   isbn      = "0-69-697269-4"
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{citations.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```