# Bracket problem with \newtheorem

Tags: theorems, brackets

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section] % reset theorem numbering for each chapter
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{props}[thm]{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\begin{props} [[1], p. 180]
\end{props}
\end{document}
```

The result would be:

> Proposition 0.0.1 ([1). , p. 180]

How do I make it like this:

> Proposition 0.0.1 ([1], p. 180)

I'm using TeXStudio with XeLaTeX.

Comment: Just write `begin{props} [[1{]}, p. 180]` or `begin{props} [[{1]}, p. 180]`.

Comment: @Bernard - I noticed your comment only after I posted my answer. I've updated the answer to mention your solution.

Comment: @Mico: That's nothing. It also happens to me from time to time. What's more important, I think, is your suggestion to use a citation command.

Comment: What's the purpose {} there? Does it work like \ in math mode? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: No, it's only a way to isolate it — for LaTeX there is an ambiguity due to the fact that you use an optional argument that is introduced by a `[`. That is  why, semantically, I prefer to write `{[1]}` rather than `[1{]}`, though both work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could load the `mathtools` package and use its commands `\lbrack` and `\rbrack` -- note that they need to be used in math mode -- to typeset square brackets in a way that doesn't trip up LaTeX. I.e., you'd write

```
\begin{props}[$\lbrack 1\rbrack]$, p.~180]
```

*Addendum*: I just noticed the comment posted by @Bernard: An even easier solution is to write

```
\begin{props}[{[1]}, p.~180]
```

---

Presumably, though, the `[1]` element is a call-out to an entry in the bibliography. Have you tried `\begin{props}[\cite{whatever}, p.~180]`, where "whatever" is the citation key of the entry in question? Assuming you're using a numeric citation style, the `\cite` command will generate the `[1]` element for you in a way that doesn't interfere with `\begin{props}`.

Comment: I wish I could use `\cite`, but I have problem with that as well: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172579/bibliography-not-showing?noredirect=1#comment398562_172579

Comment: @user74158 - I've added some comments at the end of your earlier posting. Please be more specific as to the problems you're encountering.